# How to add "close" button on a pop up?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I open a pop up and i want to add a "close" button on it. The "close" button will close the pop up when clicked.
Here is the code with open the popup:

**JavaScript**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#contener>li>a[rel=external]').click(function(){
    var mywindow= window.open(url,'','menubar=no, status=no, scrollbars=yes, menubar=no, width=1200, height=300');

    mywindow.focus();

    return false;   

    }); 
  });
```

**HTML**

```
<ul id="contener">
     <li><a href="/app/contact/user" rel="external">User</a></li>
     <li><a href="/app/contact/notuser">Not User</a></li>
</ul>
```

Thanks

Comment: How does this code open the popup?

Comment: Where do u have the pop-up here?

Comment: check [jQuery Dialog UI](http://jqueryui.com/dialog/#modal-form)

Comment: Look at [*jsFiddle updated*](http://jsfiddle.net/GKDev/gkt8f/1/)

Answer (score 1):

In pop up you just add one button, when you click on that button pop up will close.

**Example**

```
<input type="button"  value="Close" runat="server" onclick='window.close();' />
```

Answer (score 0):

Put this code inside your popup function:

```
mywindow = window.open("filename with path", "mywindow", "location=1,status=1,scrollbars=1,  width=100,height=100");
        mywindow.moveTo(0, 0);
    mywindow.close();
```